# Windows server for hobby developers?

Tags: windows, windows-server

I would like to develop server applications in C#.
At the moment I'm developing a server application with a friend in Java but I really don't like it. I like C# much better.
My problem is that the advantage of Java is that it runs on almost any system including Linux.
For my current project I rent a linux vserver and I would like to switch back to C#.
I know that there is the Mono project out there but sometimes I run into incompatibilities using it that I cannot fix or only with some workarounds.
I would like to know if there is a possibility to get a windows machine (vserver) without paying hundreds of dollars? Is there maybe another solution for hobby developers to get a windows server?

Comment: If you're a student, there is a way for you to get the Datacenter (or Standard) version of Windows Server 2012 R2 (or 2012, 2008 R2, or 2008 for that matter) for free. Microsoft runs the DreamSpark program which allows this and a bunch of other products (e.g. Visual Studio 2013, 2012, 2010, or 2008 Professional and SQL Server 2008, 2012, and 2014). See the tag wiki for the [tag:dreamspark] tag for more info. (no affiliation, it's just a program that I use myself as a high school student)

Comment: Yes I am a student and I have access to Dreamspark. I don't use it at the moment because I don't know if I'm allowed to use it for my purposes. The EULA says that I'm only allowed to use it for educational purposes associated with university research. I don't know if I'm allowed to use it but I could ask our datacenter staff.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few hosting solutions that provide Windows hosting for simple website:

- [Windows Azure Websites](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/services/web-sites/)
- [Heroku](https://appharbor.com/)

These don't provide a full Windows environmnet, but allow you to host a simple ASP.NET website for free.

To compare several different ASP.NET hosting options check out Microsoft's [comparison tool](http://www.microsoft.com/web/hosting/home).

Answer (score 2):

You unfortunately did not provide any information about what Windows Server version is required and what the nature of your project is.

Note that my following suggestions are based on your remark about being 'hobby developers'.

If Windows Home Server would be sufficient, you can still buy a license [for far below US$100](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=Windows%20Home%20Server) (check your local prices). However, before going that route, check for differences between WHS and its grown-up Windows Server brothers, and whether such differences would be of concern for you (google for something like "Windows Home Server vs. Windows Server 2008").

You can install it on a separate box, but having a PC with a decent CPU with hardware virtualization and plenty of RAM will also allow you to install and run it in in a VM (for example VMWare player, which i prefer over Virtual Box which when i tried it quite some time ago had lots of trouble with USB pass-through - but this might have been fixed since then, though).

Having a VM with the target OS allows you a rather quick and painless deployment for debugging, and it allows you to have a multitude of VMs with different system and OS configurations for testing (your available HDD/SDD space is the limit...).

Where VM's fall short is if you need to do extensive tests regarding load and performance when the server is hit with many concurrent queries. Both the VM as well as the NIC from the host PC will be a bottleneck, and also the CPU will is partially busy with the host OS. For such extensive load tests, it is recommended to have real dedicated test hardware.

Answer (score 1):

$15/mo seems to be the bottom of the market for virtual hosting with a Windows environment; and, since this is a hobby, you don't have to pay a lot of attention to the SLA and the folks behind it.